# Using a NetSuite saved search formula to filter from system notes

Tags: netsuite

I am attempting to use a NetSuite saved search to bring back system notes for whenever an assigned person changes for a case. However, I would like to grab the initial assigned person and not the multiple re-assignments after that. Is there a way for me to only select the initial value rather than having all re-assignments come back to me? Is this able to be done from a formula somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to get the oldest assignee of case you can use below criteria so, that results is restricted to just one result per case

```
1) System Notes : Field is assigned
2) System Notes : Old Value is empty
```

In the results add the column `System Notes : New Value` along with other columns of case. This field will pull the oldest assignee of the case

PS : solution assumes that there won't be any empty re-assignments. If there are empty re-assignments you should sort the results by Case unique identifier such as number or internalid and then by `System Notes : Date`, and the oldest date line would be the result that you are looking for.

Comment: Any idea on how to only return the earliest date for a specific ID, and not all assigned values? Can I do that from a basic filter?

Comment: the above solution should only pull the earliest date data , do you mean to say that you have multiple empty assignments?

Comment: My problem is that the case owner is set when created, so there are no empty rows.  I want the "New Value" from the earliest date.

Comment: in the first case the old value will be empty, right? so it should pull up the oldest assignment

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can do that with a search clause where the old value is empty